# C realloc not changing array

Tags: c, arrays, realloc

So, to start off I've already looked at a few questions including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230247/c-realloc-not-changing-apparent-size-of-character-array/) and none of them seem to help.

I'm simply trying to write a function that extends the size of an array using `realloc()`.

My code currently looks like this:

```
unsigned char *xtnd = malloc(4);
xtndc(&xtnd, 4);
// sizeof(*xtnd) should now be 8

void xtndc ( unsigned char ** bytesRef , uint8_t count ) {
    *bytesRef = realloc(*bytesRef, (sizeof(**bytesRef)) + count);
}
```

But no matter what I do it seems that the size of `xtnd` is always 4. After running `xtndc()` on it it should now be 8 bytes long.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `sizeof` doesn't give the size of the array, just the pointer itself.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers That's why I'm dereferencing it? When i do `sizeof(**bytesRef)` i dereference the dereferenced pointer, right? I'm somewhat new to C so if that's not correct let me know

Comment: Nope, not how it works. Read this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof

Comment: What did you read about the `sizeof` operator? If as pointer was an array, it would be called "array", not "pointer"

Comment: @Olaf Again, I'm somewhat new to C. I was under the impression that if i dereferenced the pointer back to it's object I could `sizeof()` the object. Now that I'm reading up on `sizeof()` (thanks to @MichaelAlbers) I see that's not how it's used. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Note: `sizeof` is not a function, but an operator. The parentheses are not part of it. And dereferencing a **pointer** yields the object it points to, which is clearly not an array here, but `unsigned char`. Your impression was very correct, but why do you think dereferencing a `unsigned char **` yields an array?

Comment: @Olaf good to know

Comment: @Olaf I was under the impression that `unsigned char* c = malloc(4);` yielded a reference to an array of unsigned chars of length 4, since directly after I could assign values to it like so `c[0] = 0x01; c[1] = 0x02; ...`. But I'm pretty sure I have a better understanding of how it works now.

Comment: @NathanFiscaletti Since `bytesRef` is an `unsigned char **`, dereferencing that gives you an `unsigned char *`, and dereferencing that gives you an `unsigned char`. What is the size of an `unsigned char`? It is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `**bytesRef` is `unsigned char`, so `sizeof(**bytesRef)` is `1`. `sizeof` doesn't keep track of dynamic allocations, it's a compile time tool that gives you the size of a type, in this case `unsigned char`.

You have to keep track of the array size manually to calculate the new required size.

Answer (score 1):

Your program does in fact change the size of the memory block. It changes the size of your original memory block from 4 bytes to 5 bytes. It changes to 5 bytes because you are essentially doing `sizeof(unsigned char) + 4` which 1 + 4 = 5. If you want to double the size instead, do `count*sizeof(unsigned char) + count`. There are two points to be noted here:

1. The `sizeof` function returns the size of the data type, not the size of the allocated bytes. There is no way to know the size of the dynamically allocated memory.
2. The function `realloc` (and `malloc` and `calloc` as well) is not always guaranteed to return the requested reallocation. It may or may not succeed all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with the following code.

```
typedef struct CArrPtr {
    unsigned char* ptr;
    size_t size;
} CArrPtr;
void xtndc ( CArrPtr *bytesRef, uint8_t count );

. . .    

CArrPtr xtnd = { .ptr = malloc(4), .size = 4 };
xtndc( &xtnd, 4 );
// xtnd.size is now 8 bytes 

. . . 

void xtndc ( CArrPtr *bytesRef, uint8_t count ) {
    unsigned char *nptr;
    if((nptr = realloc(bytesRef->ptr, bytesRef->size + count)) != 0) 
    {
        bytesRef->ptr = nptr;
        bytesRef->size = bytesRef->size + count;
    }
}
```

As I am somewhat new to C, what I learned from this is that `malloc` specifically creates a pointer to a memory block, but you have no direct access to information about the memory block. Instead, you must store the size of the array that you created with malloc somewhere as well.

Since in the past I'd been initializing arrays with `unsigned char arr[size];` and then using `sizeof` on it, I was under the impression that `sizeof` returned the size of the array, which is of course wrong as it gives you the size of a type.

Glad I could learn something from this.

Comment: But you have to call your function to do the reallocation, and then do arithmetic.  You should aim to design your code so that you don't need that split of work.  For example, you might have a structure type that keeps the pointer and the current length, and you'd pass a pointer to that structure to the `xtndc()` function so that the function can update the current length.  Also note that `old_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size);` leaks memory if the reallocation fails.  You should use: `if ((new_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size)) != 0) old_ptr = new_ptr;` or variants on that theme.  Not the test.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the suggestions! I've updated the fixed code with them, it seems to work, hopefully it's up to par :)

Comment: Looks better to me.  If you only use it once, it might be overkill, but if you use it more than that, it reduces the amount of code to be written each time.

Answer (score 0):

1. `sizeof` is used to calculate size of data type or array. Pointer and array are very similar, but they are different things. For `int *ap`, `sizeof(ap)` will return 4 on x86, `sizeof(*ap)` will return 4; for `int a[10]`, `sizeof(a)` will return 40.
2. `sizeof` expression is processed at compile time, so it will be a constant written into the executable file before you run the program.
3. `malloc` and `realloc` don't maintain size.
4. If `realloc` succeeds, it will reallocate the requested size. So you don't need to check the size after `realloc` returns, but you should check the return value of `realloc` to ensure that `realloc` succeeds.